# Javascript pass parameter to eventListener function whilst in loop

Tags: javascript

This code will pass the last value created by the loop the eventListener function, I need the value at the time the eventListener was created to be attached.

```
window.onload = function() {

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('modify');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

     var getId=el[i].id.split("_");

     document.getElementById("modify_y_"+getId[2]).addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
     document.getElementById("modify_x_"+getId[2]).style.borderBottom = '#e6665 solid 3px';
    }, false); 

}
}
```

Comment: Very common question, here is one explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @MattGreer: using closures has been best practise for years, but imo we should start teaching people to use `bind` instead since it is a superior solution and will soon be built in to all browsers that people are targeting

Comment: @MartinJespersen cool, I didn't realize you can pass args along to bind. I still haven't used it much as we support old IEs. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bind` prototype which exists on all functions in modern browsers

```
window.onload = function() {

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('modify');

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

     var getId=el[i].id.split("_");

     document.getElementById("modify_y_"+getId[2]).addEventListener('mouseover', function(theid) {
       document.getElementById("modify_x_"+getId[2]).style.borderBottom = '#e6665 solid 3px';
    }.bind(null,getId[2]), false); 

}
}
```

If you need to support older browsers that doesn't have `bind` nativly built in, you can use this [poly-fill taken from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) where you will also find documentation on the bind prototype function

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the first parameter null for btw?

Comment: The first paramater sets the `this`value of the function - since you don't need a specific `this` I set it to null - read the supplied documentation link to fully understand the function

Answer (score 1):

You do that by using a builder function:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('modify');

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {

        var getId = el[i].id.split("_");

        document.getElementById("modify_y_" + getId[2]).addEventListener('mouseover', makeHandler(getId[2]), false);

    }

    function makeHandler(theId) {
        return function () {
            document.getElementById("modify_x_" + theId).style.borderBottom = '#e6665 solid 3px';
        };
    }
};
```

The function returned by `makeHandler` closes over the `theId` argument, which doesn't change.